# Retrieve specific fields of the imported to SQL Server multiple XMLs

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlxml, sql-server-2017

I have multiple XML files with the same structure, I have imported them to *SQL Server 2017* with the following commands:

**DDL:**

```sql
CREATE DATABASE xmlFiles
GO

USE xmlFiles
CREATE TABLE tblXMLFiles (IntCol int, XmlData xml);
GO
```

**DML:**

```
USE xmlFiles
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblXMLFiles](XmlData) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\xmls\1.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblXMLFiles](XmlData) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\xmls\2.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
…
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblXMLFiles](XmlData) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\xmls\N.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

Now I want to query the data:

```
USE xmlFiles
GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XmLData FROM tblXMLFiles

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT Surname , GivenNames
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'article/ref-list/ref/mixed-citation')
WITH 
(
    Surname [varchar](100) 'string-name/surname',
    GivenNames [varchar](100) 'string-name/given-names'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

The query is working, but the problem is that it returns the data only when there is only one row in a data source table — `tblXMLFiles`. If I add more than one row, I get empty result set.

**Important:**
The situation is changing if I add to the outer `SELECT` clause (`SELECT @XML = XmLData…`) the `TOP` statement, then it returns the queried data of the specific row number, according to the `TOP` value.

How can I retrieve the data not only when there is one line in the table, but many rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more. Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Without an example of your XML it is quite difficult to offer a solution, but my magic crystal ball tells me, that it might be something like this:

```
SELECT f.IntCol 
      ,mc.value('(string-name/surname)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Surname
      ,mc.value('(string-name/given-names)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS GivenNames
FROM dbo.tblXMLFiles AS f
OUTER APPLY f.XmlData.nodes('article/ref-list/ref/mixed-citation') AS A(mc)
```

Comment: Thanks, your magic crystal ball knows how to dig into the XML! Special thanks for the link.